# Letting the server set a user value that should be observable but not editable from the client

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have very, very little experience with user data in Meteor. Here's what I want to achieve:

1. I want to set a value called `changedPassword` to `true` when the user changes his password.
2. I want this value to be observable on the client (use it to change the DOM).
3. The user shouldn't be able to change this value on his own.

I am using the [aldeed: collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) package to create a `SimpleSchema` containing the user data I want. I don't know where I should place `changedPassword`, but I guess it doesn't really matter. The only data that is observable from the client now is `emails` inside `profile`.

So, because `Accounts.changePassword` is only able to be used on the client, I need its callback to call the server to change `changedPassword` somehow, right?

```
Accounts.changePassword(oldPassword, newPassword, function(error) {
  if (! error)
    Meteor.call('changePassword')
})
```

And then:

```
changePassword: function() {
    //somehow set changedPassword to true
}
```

Also, in my template, I need to be able to view this value somehow (but without letting the user change it!). I'm assuming this requires a `deny` rule, no? No idea how it would look, though. I want to be able to do something like this in the end:

```
{{#with currentUser}}
  {{#if changedPassword}}
    <div class="show-if-user-has-changed-password"></div>
  {{/if}}
{{/with}}
```

Can someone please fill in the admittedly large blanks for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid having to call a method on the callback from `Accounts.changePassword` by using *collection2* to set your `passwordChanged` value when the password is updated directly on the server using `autoValue`. You can also set `denyUpdate` on the `passwordChanged` field in *collection2* to avoid the possibility of it being changed on the client.

It isn't that much more secure to use `Meteor.call('changePassword')` since the user could type that command straight from the console once they spot it in your code. It's trivial to find all your method endpoints by searching through the client code for `Meteor.call`.

At some later point in time you'll probably have to reset `passwordChanged` to false won't you?

Comment: Oh, that's cool. How to actually access the value, though? And no, there won't ever be a need to reset it back to `false`. Once a password has been changed, it's been changed. It's like boiling an egg. :)

Comment: Are you asking how to access *changedPassword` on the client side after it's set or how to determine when the password has been changed in your schema code?

Comment: I'm experimenting with `autoValue` unsuccessfully now so both actually! I don't know how to see it, and I don't know what field to "target" in `autoValue`. It's not `this.field("password")`

Comment: I believe you want to look at `this.field("services.password.bcrypt").isSet` in your `autoValue.`

Comment: As far as publishing the new key, you need to specifically publish the fields you want from the user's document from the server and subscribe to it from the client. e.g. `Meteor.publish('me',function(){
  if ( !this.userId ) return null;
  else return Meteor.users.find({ _id: this.userId }, { fields:
    { profile: 1, passwordChanged: 1 }});
});`